# iPhone, Access Array, local declaration hides instance variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an array in my View Controller A:

```
 fiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
 Firma * aFirma = [[Firma alloc] init];
 aFirma.title = @"title";
 aFirma.boxOfficeGross = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 200000000];
 aFirma.summary = @"summary";
 aFirma.name = @"name";
 aFirma.subtitle = @"subtitle";
 aFirma.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.33444, -122.036777); 
 [fiArray addObject: aFirma];
 [aFirma release];
```

Now I want to access the values and add them to another object in View Controller B

```
NSMutableArray *anArry = [root fiArray];
 Firma *getTitle = (Firma *) [anArry objectAtIndex:0];

 MyAnnotation *ale = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
 ale.title = getTitle;
 ale.subtitle = @"bla";
 ale.coordinate = (123,123);
 [mapView addAnnotation:ale];
```

But I always get the warning above, regarding my "getTitle" variable. And there is no value stored in `ale.title`.

Answer (score 0):

getTitle is a getter defined in UIViewController to access its title property.

Rename !

Comment: rename to "dummy" and check !

Answer (score 0):

```
use ale.title=getTitle.title;
```

and make sure all properties is readwrite

Comment: I renamend and tried ale.title=get.title, same warning.
I already synthesized fiArray in View Controller A.
If I understand the code correct, my fiArray gets stored in anArray.
I access the first entry in that array, which is the aFirma object and copy it to getTitle. So how do I have to declare getTitle?

Comment: have u set property for varaible u using in other class

Comment: in Firma class have u added these line

Comment: @property(nonatomic,assign)NSString *title;